# Remote Desktop Connection Error : Authentication error occurred. The function is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp, azure-authentication

I am trying to connect Remote Desktop to Azure VM. All the connection settings and credentials are correct. However I am getting below error from RDP.

Remote Desktop Error during Authentication error occurred. The function is not supported.

Remote Computer : xxx.cloudapp.net
**This could be due to CredSSP encryption oracle remediation.**

Answer (score 2):

I figure out the issue. It is related to group policy. MS has released a patch for this. Below solution worked for me.

> Go to -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System
>   -> Credentials Delegation -> Encryption Oracle Remediation Open - Encryption Oracle Remediation-> choose Enable ->  change protection
>   level ->Vulnerable ->Apply

Comment: This fixed connection to an Ubuntu 22.04 target (running the built-in RDP) for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better aproach would be to update both your client and server since it's a security threat not to.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4295591/credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation-error-when-to-rdp-to-azure-vm

> To resolve the issue, install CredSSP updates for both client and
>   server so that RDP can be established in a secure manner.